# How to edit minium link payment as a node-operator

Tags: nodes, oracles, chainlink

Been running a node, and I notice the payment in configuration settings is not editable, how do I figure that out, also am not seeing the Oracle balance in link increase and it debiting the user using the node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default minimum LINK payment on a Chainlink node can be set with the [`MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT_LINK_JUELS`](https://docs.chain.link/docs/configuration-variables/#minimum_contract_payment_link_juels) environment variable.

E.g. in your `.env` file:

```
MINIMUM_CONTRACT_PAYMENT_LINK_JUELS=1000000000000000000
```

Additionally, you can override this amount in your job specs.

E.g. in your job spec:

```
minPayment = 1000000000000000000
```

The amount is set in the lowest unit of LINK (which has 18 decimals). That means 1e18 = 1 LINK. To represent 0.1 LINK, you would set the value with 17 zeros, etc.